# CakePHP 3 - How do I generate a link in a view which will combine the current URL param?

Tags: cakephp, hyperlink, parameters, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x

Hello CakePHP friends.

May I have your suggestion that how can I generate a link in a view,
which is having `"?" => []` but will not clear the original param in the URL that the user is browsing?

For example,

```
<?= $this->Html->link("Blue", ["?" => ["color" => "blue"]]) ?>
```

generates a link for passing param in URL like `?color=blue`

Let say, the user clicked this link, and I want to provide him another link to add 1 or more conditions.

```
<?= $this->Html->link("Circle", ["?" => ["shape" => "circle"]]) ?>
```

generates a link like `?shape=circle`.

But I hope it will be: `?color=blue&shape=circle`.

Please help. Thank you. You can just write in answer if you have one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can find your query params in

```
$this->request->query
```

so you can use `array_merge`

```
$query = array_merge($this->request->query, ["shape" => "circle"]);
echo $this->Html->link("Circle", $query)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to combine your two `?` arrays:-

```
<?= $this->Html->link("Blue Circle", ["?" => ["color" => "blue", "shape" => "circle"]]) ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Maybe my question is not clear enough because of my bad English. But yeah, arillia's answer helps.